# How to compare 2 DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to find if there are any difference between `DateTime.UtcNow`.

`LastEdited`(9/11/2011 21:00:00) is less than 30 minutes, so the `bool` value should return a `false` since the difference is higher.

But it returned `true`. May I know what is wrong here?

```
 bool difference = ((DateTime.UtcNow - LastEdited).Minutes < 30);
```

Comment: (1) You should use `TotalMinutes`. (2) most likely `LastEdited` is not in UTC but in your local timezone.

Comment: @Murthy: The suggestion I can give you is, **search Google first** for this kind of simple issues

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you try using

```
bool difference = ((DateTime.UtcNow - LastEdited).TotalMinutes < 30);
```

The result is actually a `Timespan` and if you check for `TotalMinutes` it gives you the entire span part in minutes while `Minutes` would give only the actual minute component of the Time interval.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking at the minutes component in the time span. Check [TotalMinutes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use `TotalMinutes` instead of `Minutes`.

Minutes is just the minute part of the difference, so 1 hour and 10 minutes will cause `Minutes` to be 10, while `TotalMinutes` will cause it to be 70.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
                UtcNow = Convert.ToDateTime(UtcNowtxt.Text.Trim());
                LastEdited = Convert.ToDateTime(LastEditedtxt.Text.Trim());
                TimeSpan GetDiff = (LastEditedtxt).Subtract(UtcNow);
                if (GetDiff.Minutes < 30)
                {
                    //Do something
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

While your code will work fine when using `.TotalMinutes` instead of `.Minutes` i would suggest using

```
bool isLessThan30MinutesOld = (LastEdited.AddMinutes(30) > DateTime.UtcNow);
```

To me that's just easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
 bool difference = (DateTime.UtcNow - LastEdited) < new TimeSpan(0,30,0);
```

The only gain here is if what you're calculating your differentiating with (30 minutes) gets more complex.